# how to concatenate two column values and store in a another column mysql php

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation

I want to insert two column values(Year + ID(Primarykey-AutoIn) = SRF) in to one column

i can able to concatenate the values using the following code `SELECT CONCAT(Year, ID) AS SRF FROM billing_details` but i dont know how to insert those values in a column namely "SRF".

**Updated Question:**

Now i have used the following code

```
$sqlselect = "UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(Year, ID)";
```

it returns as "Null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by using the following code courtesy to Mr.Girish ([Column concatenation returns "Null" Mysql - Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711668/column-concatenation-returns-null-mysql-php)) and other sweet supporters(Akond, Mureinik, Jens, Valentin Rusk and etc "Thank you all for giving valuable support" )

```
//Concatenation of Year+ID=SRF
$sqlselect = "UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(`Year`, `ID`)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlselect)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(Year, ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply let me check

Comment: Result only stored as "0"

Comment: I got the following error when i about to add a row "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'SRF_3'"

Comment: You should either remove the key from the column, or device an expression, that doesn't give duplicate values.

Comment: And BTW, is not that column of integer type? It should be a string.

Comment: As mentioned above i did everything and now am getting the result as "NULL" sql code is "UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(Year, ID)"

Comment: What's the result of `show create table billing_details` ?

Comment: Table  Create Table
billing_details  CREATE TABLE `billing_details` (
 `Year` varchar(...

Comment: I don't see it. Put it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add the column to your table, assuming it does not exist yet:

```
ALTER TABLE billing_details ADD COLUMN srf VARCHAR(100);
```

And then use an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE billing_details 
SET srf = CONCAT(year, id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, i have changed the same but the result comes same "NULL"

Comment: my issue has been solved by using the following code:
//Concatenation of Year+ID=SRF
$sqlselect = "UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(`Year`, `ID`)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlselect)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}