# Column concatenation returns "Null" Mysql - Php

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, string-concatenation

I can able to concatenate the values using the following code

```
$sqlselect = "UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(Year, ID)";
```

but it returns the result value as "NULL". Kindly help me to solve this issue

**Table Structure:**

```
Year *Varchar(5)*

ID *Int(10)*

SRF *Varchar(100)*
```

Result Table:

### Year    Id     SRF

### A       1      NULL

### A       2      NULL

### A       3      NULL

Comment: Is `null`inserted in your database field `SRF`? provide some sample data.

Comment: yes null is inserted instead of the "A+10=A10"

Comment: Please add the table structure to your question.

Comment: i have updated, plz check the question

Comment: Do the $sqlselect = "SELECT Year, ID from billing_details LIMIT 10";

Comment: Your code shows the entire rows of Year and ID

Comment: Thank you for the minus after you have updated your post with data from table. check out the question now.

Comment: ALright. so show the populated data, otherwise i can't help you.
i have done it on my local db and everything worked just fine.
Received in SRF A1,A2,A3 :/

Comment: Please checkout the following link, i have post my result screenshot here http://s30.postimg.org/3rrs750kx/Null_issue.jpg    http://s1.postimg.org/9ggx6nrbj/source.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql CONCAT function is return `NULL` if any argument value if null value, see blow

```
SELECT COCAT(NULL, 1)
```

## OR

```
SELECT COCAT(1, NULL)
```

`>NULL`

If you want to keep other values while any argument value have null then use IFNULL() function to exclude NULL values

**In your query**

```
$sqlselect = "UPDATE billing_details SET SRF = CONCAT(IFNULL(Year, ''), IFNULL(ID, ''))";
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but no improvement... i think there may be some other issue

Comment: @AbdulHameed checked your source code, need seen `$sqlselect` variable query run as `mysqli_query($con, $sqlselect)`

Comment: i am very new to php and mysql plz explain clearly now what i need to do Mr.Girish...

Comment: you will need to execute sql query using `mysqli_query` function, you are using already on line no 175

Comment: Yes there i have checked the connection status

Comment: You are great Mr.Girish after adding the following line its working fine if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlselect)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}